# Nextjs Link and SEO

Tags: seo, next.js, server-side-rendering

Nextjs `Link` (next/link) seems to be a client-side redirection (as in SPAs).

Looking at News Website such as CNN, every time a link is clicked, a document is fetched as a Static Html and later the js bundles, and below-the-fold assets are fetched.

https://edition.cnn.com/africa

[image]

Even with `getStaticProps` for a page (let's call it /bla), you get 2 different behaviors:
1.while navigate to `host.com/bla` by clicking on an Dom Element using `Link`. (client-side)
2.compared with navigating directly to `host.com/bla` from a bookmark. (server side)

The question is, while using `Link`, do you lose the SEO benefits in favor of less Network activity and faster load?

How does a Search Engine Crawler treats the website? `bla.html` exists and can be served but the navigation bar in the app that uses `Link` won't lead to serving it.

I am confused how these 2 seemingly contradictory behaviors come together?

Answer (score 1):

Next.js `Link` component generates a regular `a` element with an `href` attribute when it is rendered.

The performance boosting JavaScript is layered on top of that with [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) which provides benefits to clients which support it.

Clients which don't support the JavaScript (as well as those will go directly to a particular page (e.g. when using "Open in new tab") still have the regular link to fall back on which then will give you the [pre-rendered page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) from the server.

---

[Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) gives you the best of both worlds, but is usually a lot of work to implement. Next.js does most of that work for you (at least for basic loading of pages).